# Does ZF prove that every $\Sigma_n$-axiom of ZF is true?

Tags: set-theory

According to a famous result by Levy truth of $\Sigma_n$-formulas is definable using a $\Sigma_n$-formulas (that means: If you insert a Gödel number of a formula into this defining formula, they are equivalent). Now you can obviously define the set of all (Gödel numbers of) axioms of ZF which are in $\Sigma_n$. Is it possible to prove that all these axioms are true using the definition of truth mentioned before (which is not obvious, since there might be a non-standard axiom of ZF in $\Sigma_n$)?

I think that this is actually the case: Any finite set of axioms of ZF is obviously true. It remains to consider the $\Sigma_n$-fragment of the axiom schemata of separation and replacement. These schemata are constructed using simple place-holders. Now it should be possible to transform the statement “every $\Sigma_n$-instance of the scheme is true” into an equivalent instance of the scheme itself containing somewhere inside the statement that some formula is true. But my experiences in set theory are limited, maybe there are subtle objections?

Comment: Yes. Tarski’s conditions for the partial truth predicate easily imply that the truth of an instance of replacement for a possibly nonstandard $\Sigma_n$-formula is equivalent to an instance of actual replacement for the truth predicate (with the code of the formula as a parameter), and as such it is provable.